# Display a div, if table data shows "Unpaid" with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using jquery, If I have various membership options. Can I display a certain div if the Membership Level is currently showing as "Unpaid"?

```
<tr class="swpm-profile-membership-level-row">
    <td><label for="membership_level">Membership Level</label></td>
    <td> Unpaid</td>
</tr>
```

So then change the CSS property of a div called "pay_now" on the same page.

I currently have a IF jquery working an running on the Wordpress Jquery version of 1.1.2 using

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ($('.swpm-registration-success-msg').css('display') == 'block') {
    $('.reg_intro').css('display', 'none');     
    };  
});
</script>
```

Think I need to incorporate a contain element, as shown in this example

```
 $("#X tr:contains('a')").css("background-color", "red");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

---

**ATTEMPT 1**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('td.payment_status:contains(Unpaid)') {
  $('.certain_div').css('display', 'block');        
  };
});
```

Comment: Do you have multiple .swpm-profile-membership-level-row classes on the page or just one?

Comment: Just the one class on page

Answer (score 1):

Sorry didn't understand the whole question,but if you want to show or hide a particular div on click you can use .show() and .hide() method of jquery

like suppose you have a two div like shown below

```html
<div id="id" style="display:none">Hello</div>
<div class="class">World </div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="loadMoreFun();" >submit</a>
```

Initially Hello is display none and only World show And on click submit your function should be like shown below.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function loadMoreFun() { 
  jQuery('#id').show();
  jQuery('.class').hide(); 
}
</script>
```

Now your hello is show and world is not showing.

I hope it will help you:)